# How to cancel expensive Postgresql query from Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

In my Rails application I have the controller that is responsible for generating reports. Some of those reports take a lot of time to generate, which exceed 30 seconds limit on Heroku. In such case I want to display notification to the user after 25 seconds and also cancel the database query. My initial idea was to use `Timeout`.

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  def expensive_report
    Timeout.timeout(25) do
      @results = ExpensiveQuery.new(params).results
    end
  rescue Timeout::Error
    render action: "timeout"
  end
end
```

Timing out works fine, but the respective query is not canceled. It is easy to reproduce in Rails console

```
begin
  Timeout.timeout(1) do
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT pg_sleep(10)")
  end
rescue Timeout::Error
  puts "Timeout"
end

result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT 1 AS value")
puts result[0]["value"]
```

This code will output "Timeout" and then block on line `result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT 1 AS value")` until `pg_sleep` query finishes.

How can I cancel such query from within Rails? I am hosting my app on Heroku, so priviliges are limited to run commands such as `pg_cancel_backend` or `pg_terminate_backend`.

Comment: I think the  better answer here is to use a background job for the process of generating the report instead of tying up the web worker. That way you give the user immediate feedback and free the web worker. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html

Comment: You can use [polling](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-polling) or [websockets](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html) to notify the user when its done.

Comment: @max That's my idea. I want to display a message with option to initiate background task. Those expensive queries work fine for most users, so I don't want to run it as background task for everyone.

Comment: Well except that it ties up the dynos you want free to handle requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found cool solution that does not require modifications to current queries.

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  def expensive_report
    Timeout.timeout(25) do
      @results = ExpensiveQuery.new(params).results
    end
  rescue Timeout::Error
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection.cancel
    render action: "timeout"
  end
end
```

When running in console I need to add check if connection is active.

```
begin
  Timeout.timeout(1) do
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT pg_sleep(10)")
  end
rescue Timeout::Error
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection.cancel
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.active?
  puts "Timeout"
end

result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT 1 AS value")
puts result[0]["value"]
```

Without calling `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.active?` it will raise `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::QueryCanceled`.

This works pretty nice, but I am yet sure if there are any hidden problems with that.

Comment: After reading a few articles (e.g. https://jvns.ca/blog/2015/11/27/why-rubys-timeout-is-dangerous-and-thread-dot-raise-is-terrifying/), `timeout` should be (strongly) avoided because it can raise an (interrupt) exception at any time, any line of code.

Answer (score 1):

you can set `statement_timeout` on session level (without transaction and skipping `local`).

or transaction:

```
t=# begin; set local statement_timeout to 1; select pg_sleep(3);end;
BEGIN
Time: 0.096 ms
SET
Time: 0.098 ms
ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout
Time: 1.768 ms
ROLLBACK
Time: 0.066 ms
```

or as default for the user:

```
alter user no_long_qries set statement_timeout to 1;
```

Comment: Thanks. Nice answer, but it is not possible to set it without transaction, which is a little limiting. I will need to wrap all queries in transactions. Also statement_timeout is in miliseconds.

Comment: you can set it per session, or per user

Answer (score 0):

You can make that timeout apply to all database requests by adding this to the `config/database.yml`:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  ...
  variables:
    statement_timeout: 25000
```

Or this to the end of `config/environment.rb`:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('set statement_timeout to 25000')
```

Comment: So this is problematic, because it will be set for all queries. I need to set it only for specific queries.